# If I have launched the production app on play store after beta version, does beta users count adds to number of downloads?

Tags: android

If suppose I have 100 downloads for beta version of the app, now I launch the production version, would my new downloads begin from 1 or 101?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They would begin from 1 since those prior 100 downloads were for your beta app and not the PlayStore version